# Showing Two Remainders are Equal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Hypothesis:**

1. $f = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
2. $g = x^m - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
3. $f \mid g$
4. $f^{(i)} = f(x^i) = a_0 + a_1 x^i + \ldots + a_n (x^i)^n  \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
5. $f^{(m+i)} = f(x^{m + i}) = a_0 + a_1 x^{m+i} + \ldots + a_n (x^{m+i})^n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

**Question:** From another argument, we have that $f \mid g \implies f \mid f^{(m+i)} - f^{(i)}$.  Now suppose that $f^{(i)} = fq_i + r_i$ and $f^{(m+i)} = f q_{m+i} + r_{m+i}$.  Then why does $r_i = r_{m +i}$?

**Attempt:**

1. Since $f \mid f^{(m+i)} - f^{(i)}$, we have that

   $$f^{(m+i)} - f^{(i)} = (fq_{m+i} + r_{m + i}) - (fq_{i} + r_i) = f(q_{m+i} - q_i) + (r_{m+i} - r_i) = fq$$

   for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
2. We then have that $\deg(r_{m+i} + r_i) = \deg(r_{m+i}) + \deg(r_i) < \deg(f) + \deg(f) = \deg(f)$.
3. But then why must $(r_i - r_{m+i}) = 0$ so that $r_i = r_{m+i}$ as desired?

Comment: Sorry, can you give more information on $q_i$ and $r_i$? If we set $q_i=0$ the statement is wrong. From your naming I suppose you are considering something like Euclidean Algorithm? In this case we have $deg(r_i)<deg(f)$ as you seem to have assumed silently in your prove. Your statement is then implied by the fact that $f \mid (r_{m+i}-r_{i})$ and consequently $deg(f) \mid deg(r_{m+i}-r_{i})<deg(f)\Rightarrow deg(r_{m+i}-r_i)=0$.